# .Net In-Context Popup Window Doesn't present Paypal screen

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've added the code as suggested on the Paypal Developer site.

```
<form id="myPaymentContainer" method="post"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
        paypal.checkout.setup('XUM4RANUNKG4U',
        {
            environment: 'sandbox',
            container: 'myPaymentContainer'
        });
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

The In-Context Checkout Overview describes the step:

> To check out with PayPal, the buyer clicks the PayPal Check out button.
>
> In response to the button click, these actions occur:
>
> The In-Context JavaScript opens a pop-up window and waits for your
>   form submit to create an Express Checkout payment. A successful create
>   payment call returns HATEOAS links that you use in subsequent steps.
>   Use the redirect URL from the response to redirect the buyer to the
>   PayPal URL. **If you have correctly integrated the In-Context
>   JavaScript, the pop-up window manages the redirect.**

For my OnLoad event, I'm testing with this:

```
    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);



        var transaction = new Transaction()
        {
            amount = new Amount()
            {
                currency = "USD",
                total = "20"
            },
            description = "My product description",
            item_list = new ItemList()
            {
                items = new List<Item>()
                {
                    new Item()
                    {
                        name="The Product",
                        currency="USD",
                        price="20",
                        quantity = "1"
                    }
                }
            },
            invoice_number = "123"
        };

        var payer = new Payer()
        {
            payment_method = "paypal"
        };

        var payment = new Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            transactions = new List<Transaction>() { transaction },
            payer = payer,
            redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
            {
                cancel_url = "/Home.aspx",
                return_url = "/Checkout.aspx",
            }
        };

        var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
        var paypalLinks = createdPayment.links;

        if (paypalLinks != null)
        {
            var redirectLink = paypalLinks.FirstOrDefault(lnk => lnk.method == "REDIRECT");
            if (redirectLink != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(redirectLink.href);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I add the action attribute to my `<form>`, the popup window populates with the action. I was expecting the popup window to populate with Paypal HTML so the user can log in. If I remove the action on the form, the same page hosting the button is rendered in the popup window.

**Update**

I did get this working correctly. Instead of using the form tag, I used a div:

```
<div id="myPaymentContainer" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
        paypal.checkout.setup('XUM4RANUNKG4U',
        {
            environment: 'sandbox',
            container: 'myPaymentContainer'
        });
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

I restructured the logic a bit, but it performs basically the same call to the Response.Redirect(*link*). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm posting this and setting as my answer in case people are looking that a question had an actual answer.*

My question was updated with the fix.